# Adding Zero Before Number + jQuery Pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-pagination

Is there any way to add "0" before the pagination number? now out put showing 1 2 3 4. I want to show like 01 02 03 04 05

```
<div id="pagination-container"></div>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplePagination.js/1.6/jquery.simplePagination.js'></script>
 var items = $(".list-wrapper .list-item");
    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = 5;
    var nnn = 0;
    items.slice(perPage).hide();

    if( numItems > 5 ){
    $('#pagination-container').pagination({
        items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        prevText: '<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/page-left-arrow.svg" alt="">',
        nextText: '<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/page-right-arrow.svg" alt="">',
        onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
            items.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
            $('html,body').animate({
                          scrollTop: jQuery(".regulatory-block").offset().top - 150

                        }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `String.prototype.padStart`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: can you please give any examples here? that using on jquery.. or which area I want to use that function?

Comment: i can see the duplicate answer for javascript. i want to implement the "0" in jquery pagination

Comment: Huh? jQuery _is_ javascript.

Comment: yes. but how i can implement those codes in this jquery pagination? can you please help me to do that

Comment: This questions appears to be more about how to add leading zero **on the pagination plugin** - not just add leading zeros to a variable.

Comment: @AhammedNavasK exactly which pagination plugin are you using?   The answer will depend on the options on the plugin.

Comment: am not using any plugins. just add the **jquery simple pagination**

Comment: the above code is used on the site. you can check it.

Comment: [tag:jquery] does not come with "simple pagination" - there's no `$(..).pagination()` method in *jquery*.  Can you at least provide a link to where you downloaded it?  The documentation?  Maybe [edit] your question to include your `<script src=` lines.

Comment: @freedomn-m i have updated the code.please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using jquery.simplePagination.js
>
> https://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

The pagelink is generated with this code:

```
$link = $('<a href="' + o.hrefTextPrefix + (pageIndex + 1) + o.hrefTextSuffix + '" class="page-link">' 
        + (options.text) 
        + '</a>')
```

where `options.text` is:

```
options = $.extend({
                text: pageIndex + 1,
                classes: ''
            }, opts || {});
```

given the `+1` the text will be numeric unless overwritten for next/prev buttons.  For numeric (not next/prev) links, the method that builds the page-button is called with:

```
methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
```

with no option to pass in a formatter or additional `opts` or callback.

So, out of the box, using the CDN, the answer to:

> Is there any way to add "0" before the pagination number?

is: No, not using this plugin as it is.

---

If you're ok copying the `jquery.simplePagination.js` to your site/server and linking to it there instead of from the CDN, you can change the rendering of the page number, eg from:

```
' + (options.text) + '
```

to

```
' + (options.text+"").padStart(2, "0") + '
```

note, this also applies a few lines above for the "current" page

Comment: if this ) will be added after "10"?

Comment: Always consider than answers on SO may have typos - there was an extra `;` - removed, see edit.